# Extracting pdf file using pdf clown

Tags: java, pdf, nullpointerexception

I am trying to extract PDF files using the PDF clown library, a Java library. Basically what I am doing is making the code highlight a particular string if it in the text. But the main problem is coming in extracting the PDFpdf file.

```
    Map<Rectangle2D,List<ITextString>> textString = textExtractor.extract(page);
```

what's happening is that, this piece of code is working good in all cases such as, different font, different font size, except when there are bullets in the PDF file, any kind of bullets even numbered(i, ii, iii) bullets gives the error:

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptioninIntializerError
```

Then there are some other errors in the inbuilt pdfclown library file, which I have no idea, but then there is one exception written:

```
caused by:        java.lang.NullpointerException
```

Comment: are you sure textExtractor is not null?

Comment: Please supply a sample document to allow reprocing the issue.